# Unable to create claims from securityToken, 'issuer' is null or empty c#

Tags: c#, jwt

I am trying to implement JWT token Authentication 
But while trying to ClaimsPrincipal getting an exception.

> Unable to create claims from securityToken, 'issuer' is null or empty

I am not getting what exactly is wrong in below code

```
public static string GenrateToken(string userId, string deviceId)
            {
                var time = DateTime.UtcNow;
                var symmetricKey = Convert.FromBase64String(Secret);
                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                SecurityKey securityKey = new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricKey);
                var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
                var expiry = now.AddHours(24);
                var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                {
                    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                            {new Claim("userId", userId),new Claim("deviceId", deviceId),new Claim("time", time.ToString())}
                    ),
                    Lifetime = new Lifetime(now, expiry),
                    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature, "")
                };

                var stoken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
                var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(stoken);
                return token;
            }

            public static ClaimsPrincipal GetPrincipal(string token)
            {
                try
                {
                    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                    var jwtToken = tokenHandler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;

                    if (jwtToken == null)
                        return null;

                    var symmetricKey = Convert.FromBase64String(Secret);
                    SecurityKey securityKey = new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricKey);

                    var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        RequireExpirationTime = true,
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        IssuerSigningKey = securityKey
                    };

                    SecurityToken securityToken;
                    var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out securityToken);

                    return principal;
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //should write log
                    return null;
                }


            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure It is later to answer the op, but just in case other ppl has the same problem...

Which version of JwtSecurityTokenHandler are you using?
Apparently, there is a bug that enforces Issuer validation, regardless of your setting of:

ValidateIssuer=false

It should be fixed in version 5.0.0, but there are other breaking changes that have me tied to version 4.x.x

Does your token have a iss claim?
If not, add it as:

```
new Claim("iss", issuerName),
```

Later, setup the issuer when your token is validated:

```
var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidIssuer = issuerName,
        ValidAudience = false,
        IssuerSigningKey = securityKey
    };
```

Where issuerName is any string constant that you wouldn't like to check, but you're forced to use. Even if it is not going to be validated, must exists

Bug: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/154
(You can also use the workaround described there)